# Is there a way to measure the current erogated by a psu during it's usage?

Tags: power-supply

I'm trying to test a psu, to establish if it is reliable or not. The voltages on the various connectors are ok, but I'd like to know if there's a way to measure the current that flows in the cable during the usage to be sure that the psu can support the pc hardware even when it is under heavy load.

Is there a solution for this?

Thanks

**update**

Thanks for the corrections, I'll try to be a little more precise, I'd like to measure the 18A on the 12V power line, and check that the psu can supply all the 18A, in case the pc is in full load, so that the psu won't power off,  because it can't supply all the requested current. Hope this explanation is better than the previous one.

Comment: How would measuring current tell you if the PSU can support the PC hardware? And which cable are you talking about?

Comment: Since these are DC voltages and currents, you cannot use a clamp meter, and would have to insert an ammeter.  But more often, low voltage is used to detect excessive current draw from a PSU, i.e. the voltage rail "sags" when overloaded.  BTW "erogated" is not a verb to be combined with the subject "current".

Comment: Actually, there ARE clamp-on meters that will work, but they are expensive units using Hall effect or some such.  However, it's not hard to get a PSU cable extension, cut the wires, and insert a meter.  But to assure that a PSU can supply 18A one really needs a PSU test jig with appropriate load resistor banks and instrumentation.